# Why HTTP ports stay open when using them by Nodejs servers?

Tags: node.js, http, nginx, server

I have a problem when launching a Nodejs script that listens in one of the HTTP ports. Sometimes, even if I stop the script, the used HTTP port stays "in use", making it impossible to use it another time. Today, i've set up NGINX in my linux and all the HTTP ports were "in use". I was obliged to restart  my computer to solve the problem.

I wanted to know why is this happening ? What can i do to prevent it ? and in case an HTTP port stays "in use", how can i close it to be able to use again ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you on linux or on windows?

Comment: I'm using Linux. Ubuntu actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is applicable only on Linux and MacOS**, you can list all your used ports like that:

`sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN`

Read more here about how to check if a port is in use: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-check-if-port-is-in-use-command/

You can also list the node processes:

`top | grep node`

or

`ps -ef | grep node`

Then you can kill the node processes like that:

`killall node`

Make sure that when you want to stop the server you are pressing `CTRL + C`